# Better approach for extracting data from Serve DB to local DB using APIs

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tfs, wcf-data-services

I need a better approach/way of extracting data from database through APIs and populate it in the local DB (SQL Server).

Currently I am using a website to do this and using button click to update local DB by calling the update method through APIs.

I need to make it automatically triggered like a scheduler will call the update method to update the local DB.

Let’s say I am extracting the TFS data of my project and dumping the data to local DB through TFS APIs.

I need this update method to run at regular intervals (intervals could be configured by user).

Which approach will be the best bet here. (Using .Net technology). I am considering the WCF Data Service to do this. Will this work for above constraints.

P.S. Not sure what should be the #tags to use here. Please modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. The TFS data store is a SQL Server. You could just use that instead of extracting it unless your TFS installation is heavily loaded.
2. HAve you considered SSIS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)